My parrot chewed about 1/3 of the bark from my Norfolk pine plant. The branches are hanging down; how can I save it?
My African Grey Parrot chewed the bark off about 1/3 of my Norfolk Island Pine plant. The branches are still green, but they are hanging down.
How can I save it? Is Bark wrap a good idea?  I’m willing to try but I’ve read conflicting thoughts about using it.  This plant has seen us through several Christmases and I’d hate to lose it & am willing to try any ideas.

HI Robin, it help sus answer if we can see it, please post a photo.

I don't think you have anything to lose.  I don't see how it can do much harm.  Perhaps water it a bit more.

Also couldn't hurt to spray water or run a humidifier to compensate for the struggle to draw water up to the leaves.
